# Trabalhar com JSON para request e response Java

Tags: java, json, web-service, rest, http-post

Preciso consumir um WS com rest que já esta quase completo, falta apenas 2 coisas para finalizar:
- montar o JSON do request e manipular o JSON do response.

Eis um exemplo do modelo que preciso enviar na requisição:

```
{
    "sendSmsRequest": {
        "to": "123456789",
        "msg": "funcionou"
    }
}
```

para fazer isso estou tentando usar JSON Object:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("to", "123456789");
jsonObject.put("msg", "funcionou");
StringEntity input = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
   //parametros para montar o request(Headers e Entity)
...
```

Porém, ao printar o teste, vejo que o "sendSmsRequest" não vai na requisição.
Se eu montar uma string contendo toda a requisição da certo,

```
String teste = "{\"sendSmsRequest\": { \"to\": \"123456789\",\"msg\": \"funcionou\"}}";
```

Porém, preciso achar uma solução mais elegante.
**Exite algum método no JSON object que me permite setar esse "cabeçalho"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente desta forma

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("to", "123456789");
jsonObject.put("msg", "funcionou");

JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject();
json2.put("sendSmsRequest", jsonObject);
StringEntity input = new StringEntity(json2.toString());
```

O resultado será o que você espera

Comment: Opa Marquezani, muito obrigado!
Fiz desta forma e saiu perfeitamente!!

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia,

eu recomendaria o uso do Gson. Facilitaria e muito o seu trabalho para tratamento dessas requisições.

Comment: Opa Caio, vou dar uma pesquisada aqui. Você teria algum exemplo de como montar esse request?

Comment: User user = new User();
user.setName("Teste");
user.setUsername("muitos testes");
    
Gson gson = new Gson();
String userJSONString = gson.toJson(user);